# Installing multiple instances of Chatter Mobile

Tags: chatter, mobile, salesforce1-app

I am hoping Salesforce1 really will make mobilizing existing SF functionality easier and I'd like to starting testing some stuff out. But I already have the Salesforce1 client installed on my Phone & Tablet, linked to an live org. So are there any easy ways to install a separate instance of mobile client on the same device so I can test it out with a different dev org? I know I can login/out of orgs on the mobile client, but that will get painful pretty quickly. But looks like you can't install apps on the IOS simulator, so wondered if folks have found ways round this, short of buying multiple devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to be logged into more than one org at a time, but you could use the mobile web version. Just log into your org using Safari and you'll also see the Salesforce1 interface.

Another option is to use the mobile url on the desktop: yourinstance.salesforce.com/one/one.app

Comment: Didn't know about using the URL to simulate mobile  - thanks! So I don't think I saw this anywhere - is Salesforce1 a free add on, or is there a cost like Mobile Classic?

Comment: I also remembered that with Android Tablets, you can have multiple logins on the tablet, and each of those can then have it's own login to chatter mobile, so that might help for folks with a Nexus 7 at least

Comment: Salesforce1 is a free add on.